# Search SOLR for null / not set values

Tags: solr, lucene

How do I search for documents which are missing a field?

There are 3 states:

`{ id: 1, name: "joe"}`

`{ id: 2, name: ""}` <--- How do I find this?

`{ id: 3 }` <--- How do I find this?

---

I've tried

This returns the expected result, but trying the same thing with `id:2` also returns a result?

`?q=id:3 AND -name:["" TO *]`

> `{id: 3}` this matches as expected since `name` is missing

`?q=id:2 AND -name:["" TO *]`

> `{id: 2, name: ""}` but I expect this to not match since `name` here is not missing

---

On the other hand, searching explicitly for empty fields is not as I expect:

`?q=id:2 AND name:""`

> `{id: 2, name: ""}` as expected

`?q=id:3 AND name:""`

> `{id: 3}` even though `name` here is not set

---

Can someone explain how to search for empty string vs. deleted fields?

Does it matter which goes in `fq` vs `q`?

Comment: could you try the below? *:* AND -field[* TO *] 
Where *:* is a special code for "all documents".
-field:[* TO *] is for documents that do NOT have terms in "field"

Comment: None of your examples above should return the document with `id:2` when you explicitly start with just the `id:3` query. What query parser are you using? How are you querying? Is this in the Solr UI or in your own code? Is the result from the log of the actual query sent to Solr?

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks so much for your time here. I've clarified my question with more precise examples.

Answer (score 0):

you can search for non existing fields like this

`!name:[* TO *]`

it will show you all documents where the field is not set.

If you search for fields that are in the document but empy I'll use

`name:*`